# CoreML cannot verify inputs

Tags: swift, coreml

I have a problem with CoreML, because when I want the program to verify the image there goes an error:

> [coreml] Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=1 "Input image feature
>   image does not match model description"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Input image feature image does not
>   match model description, NSUnderlyingError=0x2807c0cf0 {Error
>   Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=1 "Image is not expected type
>   OneComponent8, instead is 32ARGB"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Image is not expected type
>   OneComponent8, instead is 32ARGB}}} 2018-10-24 06:47:53.975118+0200
>   recognizeMyFood[25848:7075048] [coreml] Failure verifying inputs.

Below there is a code snipped where I have image converting:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: 343, height: 447), true, 2.0)
image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 343, height: 447))
let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

let attrs = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue, kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue] as CFDictionary
var pixelBuffer : CVPixelBuffer?
let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(newImage.size.width), Int(newImage.size.height), kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, attrs, &pixelBuffer)
guard (status == kCVReturnSuccess) else {
    return
}
```

I would be thankful if anyone could help me!

Answer (score 2):

The key is in the error message: "Image is not expected type OneComponent8, instead is 32ARGB"

You're providing it with a color image (`kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB`), but the model expects a grayscale image (`kCVPixelFormatType_OneComponent8`).